# is there any kind of unique object that can differentiate smart cards from each other

Tags: unique, smartcard

I need to know if there any kind of unique object that i can use to differentiate between smart cards
for example if i have 1000 smart cards and i need to differentiate between them without pre-write any values on them

is there any default unique value which is a factory default built-in value like the mac address for the network cards

????

how can i retrieve this value if it was there??

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of smart card.

You won't be able to use the ATR, because this will be the same for each card. However, some smart cards support a "CHUID" (card holder unique ID), many MIFARE cards support this. However, sometimes the MIFARE card is configured to report a psuedo-random value for the card ID to eliminate the chances of someone tracking the card.

My company makes a web-browser based scripting environment for smart cards that will get you started, the paypass demo shows how to get the card ID for paypass cards:

https://cardboss.cometway.com/content.agent?page_name=Paypass+Demo